# Циклы for in Java

Tags: java

почему выводится 9 раз?

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            System.out.println("Итак..");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Zein, а сколько должно?

Comment: Ну... Э-э-э... Потому что трижды три равно девять...

Comment: Кэп никого не оставит в беде, и поэтому спешит сказать, что это все потому что 3*3 = 9

Comment: Итак.. Итак.. Итак..

Итак.. Итак.. Итак..

Итак.. Итак.. Итак..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i начинает с 0 и заканчивает на 2 (потому что при 3 уже нарушается условие i<3). Т.е. всего i принимает 3 значения.

Аналогично для j. 3x3=9.

Answer (score 2):

- i = 0:

  1. j = 0
  2. j = 1
  3. j = 2
- i = 1:

  4. j = 0
  5. j = 1
  6. j = 2
- i = 2:

  7. j = 0
  8. j = 1
  9. j = 2

**ИТОГО: *9 раз***